# Migrate from Caliburn Micro with Cocktail to bare Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

Potatoes,
I'm working on a WPF Project that in the past made use of IdeaBlade's Devforce with Cocktail. We've now refactored all the code from Entity Framework data access to Json/Ormlite with ServiceStack. 
Since we had to reference Cocktail and Ideablade's assembly just for IDialogManager and FrameworkBootstrapper we implemented our own **IDialogManager** in order to exclude those assemblies. 
My issue is about how Bootstrapper creates the instances.

We use MEF for composition.

In some part of the code we use a PartFactory to create the instance... the original code was

```
public abstract class PartFactoryBase<T> : IPartFactory<T>
{
    public T CreatePart()
    {
        return Composition.GetInstance<T>(CreationPolicy.NonShared);
    }
}
```

and has been replaced by

```
public abstract class PartFactoryBase<T> : IPartFactory<T>
{
    public T CreatePart()
    {
        var res = IoC.Get<T>();

        return res;
    }
}
```

but how we do specify the CreationPolicy? Is it deduced by the CreationPolicyAttribute that flags the class? Is there a cleaner way to create a new instance?

The other part of the code where we create an instance is when a menuitem is clicked (in this case a screen is created)

Old code :

```
public void Handle(MenuMessage message)
    {
        typeSpecific = message.MenuItemType;

        IScreen screen = (Screen)Composition.GetInstance(typeSpecific, string.Empty, CreationPolicy.NonShared);
        [...]
    }
```

new version :

```
    public void Handle(MenuMessage message)
    {
        typeSpecific = message.MenuItemType;

        IScreen screen = null;

        var contract =  AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(typeSpecific);
        var exports = DOMEBootStrapper.Container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);
        if (exports.Any())
            screen =(Screen) exports.First();
        [...]
    }
```

I don't like to put this code at all since it's the same I've defined in the Bootstrapper when I need to create an instance... And how do I specify the creationpolicy?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Export(typeof(IMessageBox)), PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)] for example or it can be standalone [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)].  Also to get to the items in the Container, I suggest IoC, although some would say it's an anti-pattern, use at your own risk.